# C# Convert int to currency string with decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal, int, currency

Conversions. Blah... possibly the most confusing aspect of the language for me.

Anyways, I want to convert the int 999 to $9.99. Using ToString("C") gives me $999.00 which is not what I want.

All of my integers will work this way meaning if the price of something is 12.30 the int value will be 1230. Two decimal places, always. I know this will be easy for most, I cannot find anything here or through Google.

Also, any resources you have on conversions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try (`YOURINTVALUE` / 100).ToString("C2");

Comment: Any way you could switch to using a Decimal type?

Comment: @fardjad: Not quite; you would be performing integer division there, you would need to use `someInt / 100.0`.

Comment: @Ed S. Oh yes you're right. At least one of the operands should be (casted to) a floating point number.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your source variable is declared as an int, then one possible solution is to divide by "100m" instead of "100". Otherwise it will perform an integer division. 
e.g :

```
    int originalValue = 80;
    string yourValue = (originalValue / 100m).ToString("C2");
```

This will set yourValue to "$0.80". If you leave out the "m", it will set it to "$0.00" .

NOTE: The "m" tells the compiler to treat the 100 as a decimal and an implicit cast will happen to originalValue as part of the division.

Answer (score 6):

Just divide by 100:

```
yourValue = (originalValue / 100).ToString("C");<br>
// C will ensure two decimal places... <br>
// you can also specificy en-US or whatever for you currency format
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for currency format details.

UPDATE:

I must be slow today... you'll also have to convert to a double or you'll lose your decimal places:

```
yourValue = ((double)originalValue / 100).ToString("C");
```

(Alternatively, you could use [decimal, since it is usually the preferred type for currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I got a function for anyone who just need to divide the zeroes based on certain separator. E.g: 1250000 -> 1,250,000..

```
public static string IntToCurrencyString(int number, string separator)
{
    string moneyReversed = "";

    string strNumber = number.ToString();

    int processedCount = 0;

    for (int i = (strNumber.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        moneyReversed += strNumber[i];

        processedCount += 1;

        if ((processedCount % 3) == 0 && processedCount < strNumber.Length)
        {
            moneyReversed += separator;
        }
    }

    string money = "";

    for (int i = (moneyReversed.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        money += moneyReversed[i];
    }

    return money;
}
```

Enjoy!